# How to pass variables from select option to TypeScript function at Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

select-option loop at myComponent.html:

```js
      <select class="form-select" (change)="selectOption($event)">
        <option *ngFor="let entity of entities; let i = index"
          value="{{entity.id}}" [selected]="i == 0 ? true : null" 
          (onload)="fooFunction(i, entity.id)">{{entity.name}}
        </option>
      </select>
```

and myComponent.ts function:

```js
  fooFunction(i: number, entityId: number){
    console.log(`${i} - ${entityId}`);
  }
```

I want to pass variables to function while populating options. I tried `load` , `onload` , `onSelect` etc.

How can I achieve this in `angular13`?

Answer (score 1):

Your `selectOption($event)` could reflect that by passing your variables in an array on change.

In TS

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  entities = [
    { id: 1, name: 'hello' },
    { id: 2, name: 'test' },
  ];

  selectOption(event: any) {
    const arr = event.target.value.split(',');
    console.log(arr[0]); //id
    console.log(arr[1]); //index
  }
}
```

Html

```html
<select class="form-select" (change)="selectOption($event)">
  <option *ngFor="let entity of entities; let i = index" [value]="[entity.id, i]">
    {{ entity.name }}
  </option>
</select>
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qzdsfl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: `(change)="selectOption($event)"` passes variables perfectly but the problem is that this solution needs a change i.e. click event. Unlike this case, variables need to be passed when loading options without any click or change. So, the answer needs to be edited.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ngModel

```
 <select class="form-select"  [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
        <option *ngFor="let entity of entities; let i = index"
          [ngValue]="entity.id">{{entity.name}}
        </option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Support for using the ngModel has been deprecated in Angular v6. For more information: https://angular.io/guide/deprecations